# Joint Probability density function

Tags: probability

Two components in rocket operate independently and the probability that each component fail is p. Let X denote the number of launches require to have a failure of component 1 and Y denote the number of launches require to have a failure of component 2.

Assuming the launches are independent show that both x and Y follow geometric sequence.

Let Z=X+Y. find Z and is Z and X independent?

And this is what i tryied!!

[image]

Comment: $T$ is what now?

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far?  You get better responses when you show how much effort you've put into it.

Comment: @GRaham it was type. I edit the question

Answer (score 0):

$X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables (it makes no sense to talk about $3.547$ launches), and being the sum of two discrete variables, $Z$ is also discrete. Integrating isn't the way to go then.

We want to find, for $z\in \mathbb{N}$, $f_Z(z)=P[Z=z]$. Now note that, by independence:

$$f_Z(z)=P[Z=z]=P[X+Y=z]=\sum_{k=0}^{z}f_{XY}(k,z-k)=\sum_{k=0}^{z}f_X(k)f_y(z-k)=\sum_{k=0}^{z}p(1-p)^kp(1-p)^{z-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{z}p^2(1-p)^z=(z+1)p^2(1-p)^z$$

I've assumed that $X$ and $Y$ can take the value $0$. This is consistent with the formula for the geometric distribution, but I guess it would depend on your interpretation of what "0 launches" actually means. If $X,Y≥1$ the modify the summation and sum from $k=1,...,z-1$.

For the independence I give you the following hint:

What is $P[Z=2|X=3]$? Compare with $P[Z=2]$.

Comment: Thanks Reveillark. I just have one more question 
We know X and Y are independet. T=X+Y;  are T and X independent? My answer is No. from T=X+Y it is clear that T depends on X, but want to double check? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is *close*.  You have the right principle; convolution is the method needed.

However, as you are dealing with *discrete* random variables, rather than continuous, you need to do this for *a series* instead of integration.

$\begin{align}
P_Z(z) & = \sum_{x=0}^z P_X(x)\cdot P_Y(z-x)
\\ & = \sum_{x=0}^z p(1-p)^x\cdot p(1-p)^{z-x}
\\ & = p^2 (1-p)^z \sum_{x=0}^z 1
\\ & = (z+1) p^2(1-p)^z
\end{align}$

For independence can you determine what $P_{Z\mid X}(z\mid x)$ is, and whether this is this equal to $P_Z(z)P_X(x)$?

Comment: Thanks Graham. I just have one more question We know X and Y are independet. T=X+Y; are T and X independent? My answer is No. from T=X+Y it is clear that T depends on X, but want to double check? Thanks

Comment: @GoitomHasa Yes, it's clear that $T$ cannot be less than a given $X$, so there is a dependence.

Comment: Thank you very much!! But i was trying to determine fz/x(z/x)=fzx(z,x)/fx(x)
But how can i find fzx(z,x)? Sorry for my unclear way of writing. I am new to this site!

Comment: @GoitomHasa Hint: you have already figured out that $P(Z=z, X=x) = P(Y=z-x, X=x)$ so thuswise: $f_{Z,X}(z,x)= f_{Y,X}(z-x, x)$